# JSON Array Index Order

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, indexing

There's a system that inputs lines of text as an array e.g., array[123,556,"test",0,0].  When using val().split('\n') i'm able to get each new line to be added to the new array so that each line index is incremented by 1 e.g.,

```
array[123,556,"test",0,1] = "line 1"
array[123,556,"test",0,2] = "line 2"
array[123,556,"test",0,3] = "line 3"
array[123,556,"test",0,4] = "line 4"
```

But I need the last two indexes to display in reverse.  The arrays need to look like this:

```
array[123,556,"test",1,0] = "line 1"
array[123,556,"test",2,0] = "line 2"
array[123,556,"test",3,0] = "line 3"
array[123,556,"test",4,0] = "line 4"
```

Somehow they're able to get the array index to increment in the 4th index.  I'm only able to get it to increment in the 5th index..  I tried .push(0) to add a 0 the end but get errors.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: what you are showing is syntactically incorrect so it is very hard to help without seeing some real code

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to splice (remove) the index out of the array, and push it back onto the end of the array.

```
var arr = [123,556,"test",0,1];
console.log(arr);  // [123, 556, "test", 0, 1] 

arr.push( arr.splice(3,1)[0] );
console.log(arr); // [123, 556, "test", 1, 0]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5wxcd3ux/

Comment: Very nice, thank you.  I will give it a try.  Nothing happened when I tried jsfiddle btw.

Comment: Did you open up the console?   There should be some output printed there.